# Gloss effect like that images sent in native sms app?

Tags: image, ios, sms, draw

I want a gloss effect like that images sent in native sms app, I saw that native sms app used a ImageBubbleMask and a ImageBubble to achieve the effect. Can anybody tell me how to do this? Any answer is appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following tutorial and see if it helps do what you're after? http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-bubble-ui-iphone-apps